# How to load index.html in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I built my app in Vue and my backend using FastAPI in Python. After I did `npm run build` I copied the `dist` folder into the `templates` folder. I want to load `index.html` but I got the error `error_aborted 404 (not found)`. The `static` folder is inside `templates` folder. Why am I getting this error?

```py
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="templates"))

@app.get("/")
def serve_home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", context= {"request": request})
```

I also tried the following code, and putting the `dist` folder in the `static` folder with no `templates` folder.

```py
@app.get("/")
async def index():
    return FileResponse('static/index.html', media_type='text/html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this:

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="templates"))
```

with this:

```
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="templates"))
```